# Prove ${\rm Hom}_\mathbb{Z}(\mathbb{Z}_n,\mathbb{Z}_m)\cong \mathbb{Z}_{m,n}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-homomorphism

Prove ${\rm Hom}_\mathbb{Z}(\mathbb{Z}_n,\mathbb{Z}_m)\cong \mathbb{Z}_{m,n}$

I think we can definine a map

$$\phi: \mathbb{Z}_n \to \mathbb{Z}_m,$$

where $\phi \in {\rm Hom}_\mathbb{Z}(\mathbb{Z}_n,\mathbb{Z}_m)$

Then $\pi :{\rm Hom}_\mathbb{Z}(\mathbb{Z}_n,\mathbb{Z}_m) \to \mathbb{Z}_{m,n}$

$\phi \mapsto t$ which is the lowest common denominator of $m,n$.

Then we show this is an bijective and a ring homomorphism.

First, I'm still working through this notation and I'm not sure if things above make sense. Second defining my map $\pi$ is weird because I'm not sure how we express an element in $\mathbb{Z}_{m,n}$

Comment: Did you try $\pi(\phi) = \phi(1)$?

Comment: We choose $\pi(\phi) = \phi(1)$ because that describes the whole homomorphism? If we use the property $\phi(1*s)=\phi(1)\phi(s)$ we can say what the other elements are? But from here I'm a little confused about how we use this to show we have the isomorphism

Comment: Here's another way to think of this problem: every homomorphism $\phi:\mathbb{Z}_n \to \mathbb{Z}_m$ is uniquely determined by $\phi(1)$ because $1$ generates $\mathbb{Z}_n$. Think about all of the possibilities for $\phi(1)$. Remember that $\phi$ must satisfy $m*\phi(1) = 0$ and $0 = \phi(0) = \phi(n*1) = n*\phi(1)$.

Comment: Aren't we talking about $\mathbb{Z}$-modules here? So $\phi(1*s) = 1*\phi(s)$? Or are you asking about ring homomorphisms?

Comment: Were talking about z-modules

Comment: Im not sure how $Z_{m,n}$ factors in

Comment: I think your definition of $\pi$ is a bit confusing because it requires you to take $\phi(1)$ and mod it to be an element of $\mathbb{Z}_{(m,n)}$.

Instead you could define $\pi:Hom_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Z}_n,\mathbb{Z}_m) \to \mathbb{Z}_m$ by $\pi(\phi) = \phi(1)$. It is not an isomorphism by itself, but you can prove that it is injective, so $Hom_{\mathbb{Z}}(\mathbb{Z}_n,\mathbb{Z}_m) \cong \textrm{Im } \pi$. Then show this image is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}_{(m,n)}$.

Comment: Doesnt the $im  \pi \in \mathbb{Z_m}?$ Why would it be isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z_{m,n}}$

Comment: $\textrm{Im } \pi$ is a submodule of a cyclic module $\mathbb{Z}_m$, so $\textrm{Im } \pi$ is automatically cyclic. All you have to show is that this image only contains $(m,n)$ elements. Because there is only one unique $\mathbb{Z}$-module of order $(m,n)$, it immediately follows that $\textrm{Im } \pi \cong \mathbb{Z}_{(m,n)}$.

Comment: I am missing something here, isn't $Z_{(m,n)}= (Z\setminus (m,n))^{-1}Z= \{\frac{a}{q}:\ q\neq \alpha m + \beta n \ \forall \alpha , \beta \in Z\}$ the localization of $Z$ at the ideal $(m,n)$ ??

Comment: Clearly this is not the case, $Z_{m,n}$ here is $Z_m\otimes Z_n$

Answer (score 1):

One can show more generally that for a one-dimensional principal ideal domain $R$ and any elements $a$ and $b$ of $R,$ we have that $$\operatorname{Hom}_R\!{\left(\frac R {aR}, \frac R {bR}\right)} \cong \frac R {\gcd(a, b) R} \cong \frac R {aR} \otimes_R \frac R {bR}.$$ Convince yourself first that $\operatorname{Hom}_R(R/I, M) \cong (0 :_M I) = \{x \in I \,|\, x \cdot m = 0\}$ for any commutative unital ring $R,$ any ideal $I$ of $R,$ and any $R$-module $M.$ Considering that $R / I$ is cyclic, a well-defined $R$-linear map $\varphi : R / I \to M$ is uniquely determined by $m = \varphi(1_R + I).$ Consequently, for any element $x$ of $I,$ it follows that $$x \cdot m = x \cdot \varphi(1_R + I) = \varphi(x + I) = \varphi(0_R + I) = 0.$$ Can you construct an isomorphism $\psi : \operatorname{Hom}_R(R/I, M) \to (0 :_M I)$? Once you have established this, apply it to the case that $I = aR$ and $M = R / bR$ to show that $\operatorname{Hom}_R(R/aR, R/bR) \cong (0 + bR :_{R/bR} a),$ where $$(0 :_{R/bR} a) = \{r + bR \,|\, ra + bR = 0 + bR\} = \{r + bR \,|\, b \text{ divides } ra\} = (b :_R a)/bR.$$ Last, you must prove that $(b :_R a)/bR \cong R / dR,$ where we denote $d = \gcd(a, b).$ Consider the map $$\gamma : R \ni r \mapsto \frac{\operatorname{lcm}(a, b)} a r + bR \in \frac{(b :_R a)}{bR}.$$ Of course, we must convince ourselves that $\gamma$ is well-defined and surjective with $\ker \gamma = dR.$ But this can be achieved by manipulating the identity $ab = \gcd(a, b) \operatorname{lcm}(a, b).$

Ultimately, the question you have asked is a special case of this with $R = \mathbb Z.$